# How can I get data from the /dev/ttyS0 port on the SIM7600E-H Rpi 4 model when the internet is on?

Tags: serial-port, raspberry-pi4, sim7600

When I want to receive data via GPS, the /dev/ttyS0 serial port is busy and I cannot receive data. I cannot make calls or SMS. I can receive GPS data when the internet is turned off.

I would like your support on this issue.

There is no problem with permissions. The problem is that I cannot communicate with GPS and the internet at the same time.

Comment: You're leaving out details, and seem to assume that we know exactly what you have. Since you only mention **/dev/ttyS0** on the host side, seems like you're trying to do everything through the UART; are you using the test/demo programs?  FYI you really don't want to access the "*internet*" through a UART interface. You want to use a network-capable interface, such as the USB port. You would also need to install appropriate driver(s). This isn't a programming question, so vote to close.

Comment: https://andino.systems/4g-modem-sim7600/ppp
I followed these steps to connect to the internet and there is internet access.

I can't get data for GPS unless the internet is turned off. Because the serial port is busy